# sqoop: import-all-tables not importing all tables

Tags: sqoop

I used:

```
sqoop import-all-tables --m 1 --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db --username retail_dba --password cloudera --hive-import --create-hive-table  --hive-overwrite --hive-database default --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse
```

I see only categories table is imported. We have 6 tables in MySQL.

Aftr importing this table, I see categories dir and command not exiting.

When I logged in to hive, I don't see any tables under default table.

I am using by default setting comes with CDH 5.12.
Not changed any configurations. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in your command, Check whether the default schema is having any tables before use run the command.

Or create a new DB and execute the command.

```
hive> create database retaildb;
OK
Time taken: 0.38 seconds
hive> use retaildb;
OK
Time taken: 0.023 seconds
hive> show tables;
OK
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_retail_db |
+---------------------+
| avrotable           |
| categories          |
| customers           |
| departments         |
| departments_new     |
| order_items         |
| orders              |
| products            |
| products_replica    |
| tablewithboolean    |
| test                |
+---------------------+
```

Execute sqoop command.

```
sqoop import-all-tables --m 1 --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db --username retail_dba --password cloudera \
--hive-import --create-hive-table  --hive-overwrite --hive-database retaildb --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/retail_db


hive> show tables;
OK
avrotable
categories
customers
departments
departments_new
order_items
orders
products
products_replica
tablewithboolean
test
Time taken: 0.24 seconds, Fetched: 11 row(s)
```

Comment: why are you using the retail_db as your database target for the warehouse directory. Shouldn't that be retaildb.db since that is where we are trying to import all the tables to?